# Azure Function App not showing up in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I can not find the Azure Function Icon, when I try to create a new Project. 
My current Visual Studio version is 15.9.7 and I own a Azure subscription. I can create an Azure Function in VS Code but not in my regular Visual Studio. Azure Developement is installed

[image]

My Setup in the VS Installer: 
 
[image]
When I try to install azure functions manually, I get this error: 
[image]

Does anyone know, what the problem is?

Comment: Can you confirm whether you have installed the extension [Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#check-your-tools-version)?

Comment: yes, I tried to install it andI got a message box which told me, it is already installed

Comment: I would suggest your uinstall, restart the computer then re-install

Comment: is .net 4.7 installed?

Answer (score 1):

it seems this is a generic problem , a github issue is created in here:
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/399

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Azure features from the VSTS installer. You are also missing the ARM Template option, which indicates you don't have the feature installed.

The VS Installer is what is used to install VS and is in the start menu:

[image]

Comment: what is the VSTS installer and where can I get it?

Comment: It is what you used to install visual studio, it should be available in your start menu